# bash variable does not keep command result

Tags: bash, variable, command

## Problem:

Storage of the command result in variable `portcheck` does not work as expected.
My script contains this method

```
#!/bin/bash
...

status() {
    portcheck=$(nc -z -v -w5 localhost 8443)
    echo "*${portcheck}*"
    if [[ $portcheck == *refused* ]]; then
          echo "Application is stopped"
    elif [[ $portcheck == *succeeded* ]]; then
          echo "Application is started"
    else
          echo "state unknown"
    fi
}
```

When I execute myscript, I get this result:

```
> $  ./myscript status 
> Connection to localhost 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
> ** 
> state unknown
```

But what I would like to have is that the result of the command is stored in varaible `portcheck` and the output should look like

```
> $  ./myscript status 
> Connection to localhost 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
> *Connection to localhost 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!* 
> Application is started
```

I tried several variants according 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash
and others
e.g.

```
portcheck=`nc -z -v -w5 localhost 8443`
```

instead of

```
portcheck=$(nc -z -v -w5 localhost 8443)
```

But it didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

## Background:

The command

```
nc -z -v -w5 localhost 8443
```

checks if the port is connectable.
It returns

```
Connection to localhost 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

if port is "open" and

```
nc: connect to localhost port 8443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

if port is "closed".

This works fine if I just execute the command plain in the bash.

Comment: You will probably be better served using -o with nc to output the result to screen and then parse the file for the variable portcheck

Comment: Looks to me like nc is outputting the results to stderr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nc` call basically prints to stderr and you need to send the output to stdout as follows:

```
portcheck=$(nc -z -v -w5 localhost 8443 2>&1)
echo "*${portcheck}*"
```

This would be the output, in this case:

```
*Connection to localhost 8443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!*
```